# Portable way to build up arguments for a utility in shell?

Tags: shell, busybox

I'm writing a shell script that's meant to run on a range of machines. Some of these machines have bash 2 or bash 3. Some are running BusyBox 1.18.4 where `bin/bash` exists but

- `/bin/bash --version` doesn't return anything at all
- `foo=( "hello" "world" )` complains about a syntax error near the unexpected `"("` both with and without the extra spaces just inside the parens ... so arrays seem either limited or missing

There are also more modern or more fully featured Linux and bash versions.

What is the most portable way for a bash script to build up arguments at run time for calling some utility like `find`? I can build up a string but feel that arrays would be a better choice. Except there's that second bullet point above...

Let's say my script is `foo` and you call it like so: `foo -o 1 .jpg .png`

Here's some pseudo-code

```
#!/bin/bash

# handle option -o here
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)

# build up parameters for find here
parameters=(my-diretory -type f -maxdepth 2)
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    parameters+=-iname '*$1' -print
    shift
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    parameters+=-o -iname '*$1' -print
    shift
done

find <new positional parameters here> | some-while-loop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use mostly-POSIX sh, such as would be available in busybox ash-named-bash, you can build up positional parameters directly with [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html)

```
$ set -- hello
$ set -- "$@" world
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
hello
world
```

For a more apt example:

```
$ set -- /etc -name '*b*'
$ set -- "$@" -type l -exec readlink {} +
$ find "$@"
/proc/mounts
```

Comment: If I use `set --` inside my script, does that discard the arguments that were passed in originally? I'm using those to build arguments for `find` ...

Comment: When you pass positional parameters they are available in the `"$@"` variable. So if you want to add _more_ positional parameters, you must do something like `set -- "$@" --more --more --more`. Make sense?

Comment: Oh. What I wanted to do was turn each of my scripts positional parameters into something for `find` and then call `find`. But here `"$@"` is being used for both...

Comment: @user1011471 give an example in your question and I'll be able to help more. For example, show how it works in modern bash on a known OS and ask for help making it work in POSIX sh.

Comment: @user1011471, you can put the `set --` inside a function, so it'll only discard the function's arguments, rather than your entire script's argument set.

Comment: Or I suppose I could `set -- "$@" some-magical-value` and then process-and-shift until I arrive at it. Shift once more and that's what goes to `find`

Answer (score 2):

While your question involves more than just Bash, you may benefit from reading the Wooledge Bash FAQ on the subject:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

It mentions the use of "set --" for older shells, but also gives a lot of background information. When building a list of argument, it's easy to create a system that works in simple cases but fails when the data has special characters, so reading up on the subject is probably worthwhile.